# Understanding jmeter terms and result

Tags: jmeter

I am using jmeter to test my web application on tomcat. I just wanted to know the meaning of terms in simplest word:[image] [image]`Deviation` `Throughput` `Average` `Median` `No of Sample`

I have tested with

```
Number of thread(Users):1000
Rampup Period:1
Loop Count:1
```

No extra settings.

I am attaching the pics for reference. Can anyone tell whether result is good or not ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No of Sample: Total number of requests sent to server during the test.

Average : Mathematical average of the Response times. This is the number which is quoted as your average response time of your http service.

Deviation : Mathematical standard deviation of the Response times. This shows how much the response time varies. Higher values means problem.

Ideally, your average, max and min Response times should be same. Of course, this is not a practical option. So you will target to keep the deviation as low as possible. Higher values generally means system stress - unless you are writing some kind of exponential backoff operations. Your Min and Max values shows very high difference and your deviation is way too high. If you are writing a simple HTTP service, you min - max values should have similar RT values.

In summary , For me,  your Jmeter test result really looks scary and is leading me to believe you had run the test and the server on same machine leading to machine getting overloaded.Or the code is really buggy and gets bogged down on load.

Throughput : Simple term to define number of requests you can process per second or minute.

Median :  Mathematical Median of the RT. Arrange the RTs in order and select the middle value. This should be as close to average value as possible.

Comment: Yes i am running test and server on same machine. What should be ideal values in my given case. Some idea.

Comment: Your min time is 17 ms. The Average and Max time should be around this time. Your Max is 135 sec - Way too high deviation ...

Comment: Actually, you are running your test in a wrong way. Number of threads means you will have 1000 threads sending request to server all in 1 second. This is wrong - until you are using Big Big Big Machine. You should set the number of threads to max 4-10 depending on cores you have. Then set the number of execution accordingly. Num of execution = Total request you want / total threads

Comment: i tested with 5 thread, ramp up peraiod 2, loop count 1. In report it display total avg 202, min 10, max 695 is it good

Comment: Still your max is taking 695 which is 69 times the min ... Looks problematic to me... However, it is a great improvement. For any definitive binary yes or no answer, I will need to get into details of the requirement, architecture, threading, request processing and stuff ... If you are working on making your system perform better - you should start looking for bottlenecks in your system - Most naive way is to write start and end time in each method block. For better ways - search for Profiling an App in google. Please accept my answer as solution - as the original question has been answered :)